# How to modify field in ecto by Algorithm

Tags: database, postgresql, elixir, ecto

Hello everyone i'am looking for method to change field types and convert its values during this.
I mean something like that:

```
def up do
  alter table(:users) do
    modify :role, :integer, default: fragment("convertion_function")
  end
end
```

I know [`Ecto.Migration#modify/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#modify/3) function gets *`&fragment/1`* argument. But it gets only one argument.
Does anyone know if it possible to pass current value to *`&fragment/1`* function?
Or maybe anyone know better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, this can be done by specifying a `USING` clause to the `ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <column>` query. I couldn't find any support for this in Ecto's migration. You can use `execute` to execute a raw query to do this. Here's how you'd alter the `posts` table's `title` column from a string to integer and set the new value to be the length of the original titles:

```
def up do
  execute """
    alter table posts
      alter column title
        type integer
        using length(title);
  """
end
```

`length(title)` being the fragment expression which calculates the new value.

You'll want to write a similar query for the reverse migration as well.

You can read more about `USING` in `ALTER TABLE` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html).

Answer (score 1):

`default` would set the default value for new rows, it has nothing to do with the conversion of existing data.

AFAIK, there is no way to modify the column type without losing the data in PostgreSQL/MySQL. The only way would be to create a new column with migration #1, migrate existing data there with migration #2 and remove old column + rename the new column to the old name with migration #3.